# Where can I find qml types in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, extend

I heared that `qml` types is implemented in C++ ,So where can I find the C++ Classes of these types? For example I want to extent `WebView` But What is the class of `WebView` in c++?

I have read in [Writing QML Extensions with C++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html) how extend `Item`.But I don't see all `qml` types.Where is another `qml` types? For Example Where is `QQuickWebView`,Because I don't see this class in [Qt Quick C++ Classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-module.html),And How can I find that the C++ class of `WebView` is `QQuickWebView`?

```
class PieChart : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(PieSlice* pieSlice READ pieSlice WRITE setPieSlice)
    ...
public:
    ...
    PieSlice *pieSlice() const;
    void setPieSlice(PieSlice *pieSlice);
    ...
};
```

But When I want to use Header File

```
#include<QQuickWebView>
```

I see

> error: 'QQuickWebView' file not found

Comment: I think the Webview is implemented with this code: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtwebview/src/webview/qquickwebview.cpp.html

Comment: I want to extend it.But there is not in headerfiles

Comment: It is in header files, but private header file. What do you want to extend? Maybe you can simply extend that in QML

Comment: on my system: /home/{user}/qt/{qtversion}/Src/qtwebview/src/webview/qquickwebview.cpp